# TypeError: must be str, not float (Python, return value)

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python with [CS Dojo's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSbOtYzIQI0). I'm currently working on the task he gave us, which was building a "miles to kilometers converter". The task itself was very simple, but I want to build a program that does a little more than that. I want the output to be like

"The distance" + "name (ex. from NewYork to Washington)" + " is" + (Value) + " in kilometers."

but it is giving me the same error message over and over.
My code is

# miles variables
    name1 = "from_NewYork_to_Washington"
    miles1 = 20

```
name2 = "from_Boston_to_Dallas"
miles2 = 30

name3 = "from_Tokyo_to_Seoul"
miles3 = 40

#define function
def conver(name, distance):
    d = distance * 1.6
    print("result: ")
    print(d)
    return "The distance" + name + "is" + d + "in kilometers."

# result variables
result1 = conver(name1, miles1)
result2 = conver(name2, miles2)
result3 = conver(name3, miles3)
```

The error message is following:

```
result: 
32.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-4d54c2c21df2> in <module>()
     17 
     18 # result variables
---> 19 result1 = conver(name1, miles1)
     20 result2 = conver(name2, miles2)
     21 result3 = conver(name3, miles3)

<ipython-input-135-4d54c2c21df2> in conver(name, distance)
     14     print("result: ")
     15     print(d)
---> 16     return "The distance" + name + "is" + d + "in kilometers."
     17 
     18 # result variables

TypeError: must be str, not float
```

Thanks.

Comment: Convert `d` to string: `return "The distance" + name + "is" + str(d) + "in kilometers."`. You can't add `float` to string.

Answer (score 0):

The value **d** needs to be converted into a string before it can be concatenated with the rest of the return statement:

```
d = str(distance * 1.6)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Python 3.6+, f-string saves your time typing ugly quotes and plus signs and improves the readability a lot.

```
return f"The distance {name} is {d} in kilometers."
```

You can also do formatting easily inside f-strings

```
return f"The distance {name.title()} is {d:.2f} in kilometers."
```